# How to create multiple ListViews with fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Actually I want to create three listviews with the help of fragments. Is it possible? if possible then please give some reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/